# How to load html with iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have:

> index.html

and

> test.html

and I could load my `test.html` with jquery load(); function to in `index.html`

but then my index.html style is broken that is why I want to load my `test.html` into `index.html` as iframe..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>index.html</h1>

<div class="item">
load test.html here with iframe
</div>
```

```html
<div class="test">
I'm a test div and I want to be in index.html in `item` class
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to load html file into an iframe

```
<html>
<body>

  <iframe src="test.html">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to specify only the content you want to load when using `jQuery.load` like this:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "test.html #container" );
```

Then it would only load the content of #container instead of everything (including the styles which might break your layout.

---

If you want to change an iframe src with jQuery you could use a click event like so:

```
jQuery( function() {
  $( 'button' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( '#result' ).attr( 'src', 'test.html' );
  } )
} )
```

But I think it would be better to use the first approach, trying to only load the content itself, not the whole HTML structure of `test.html`.

I hope that helped :)